# ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware indivo_server.indivo.middlewares.authentication: "cannot import name HTTPRequest

Tags: python, django, wsgi, django-settings

I am building proof of concept with Indivohealth on ubuntu 14.10. I have installed both server and UI with Mysql.

http://indivo.smartrx.in:8002  -- UI server url

http://indivo.smartrx.in:8001  -- Indivo server url [ This shows internal server error and given below were the logs]

```
 [Mon Jan 18 12:48:23.888096 2016] [:error] [pid 28663] [client IP:39138] mod_wsgi (pid=28663): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/sample/indivo_server/django.wsgi'.
    [Mon Jan 18 12:48:23.888199 2016] [:error] [pid 28663] [client IP:39138] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Mon Jan 18 12:48:23.888253 2016] [:error] [pid 28663] [client IP:39138]   File "/var/www/html/sample/indivo_server/django.wsgi", line 40, in __call__
    [Mon Jan 18 12:48:23.888399 2016] [:error] [pid 28663] [client IP:39138]     return self.application(environ, _start_response)
    [Mon Jan 18 12:48:23.888435 2016] [:error] [pid 28663] [client IP:39138]   File "/var/www/html/sample/indivo_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
    [Mon Jan 18 12:48:23.888631 2016] [:error] [pid 28663] [client IP:39138]     self.load_middleware()
    [Mon Jan 18 12:48:23.888673 2016] [:error] [pid 28663] [client IP:39138]   File "/var/www/html/sample/indivo_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    [Mon Jan 18 12:48:23.888950 2016] [:error] [pid 28663] [client IP:39138]     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
    [Mon Jan 18 12:48:23.888998 2016] [:error] [pid 28663] [client IP:39138] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware indivo_server.indivo.middlewares.authentication: "cannot import name HTTPRequest"


Indivo_server - settings.py ->> 

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'indivo_server.indivo.middlewares.authentication.Authentication',
    'indivo_server.indivo.middlewares.paramloader.ParamLoader',
    'indivo_server.indivo.middlewares.authorization.Authorization',
    'indivo_server.indivo.middlewares.audit.AuditWrapper'
)
```

I have folder indivo i.e. /var/www/html/sample/indivo_server/indivo which holds all the middlewares and other folders.

Issues I am trying to solve:

1. Not able to login on UI server with johnsmith@example.org / jsmith / password.example
2. Indivo server issue

I have spent more than 3 days to setup and one day on this issue please help me to fix these .

Highly appreciated your help.

Comment: How does the code of the indivo middleware look like?

Comment: from indivo.accesscontrol import security
from indivo.lib.utils import DjangoVersionDependentExecutor

class Authentication(object):
  def process_request(self, request):

    self.avoid_post_clobbering(request)

    request.principal, request.oauth_request = security.get_principal(request)

  
  noclobber_map = {'1.3.0': lambda request: request.POST,
                   '1.3.1+': lambda request: request.raw_post_data,
                   }
  avoid_post_clobbering = DjangoVersionDependentExecutor(noclobber_map)

Answer (score 0):

My sys.path has system wide python paths as well so I have removed those path and only kept the virtualenv path only. after that I have add module paths in .pth file and kept under "site-packages" environment folder. problem solved. :-)